# como apagar o ionic por completo da máquina

Tags: ionic, windows

Alguém pode me ajudar?

galera, estou executando npm uninstall -g ionic para desinstalar o ionic, mas apresenta seguintes erros:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\ender\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
[90m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:982:15)[39m
[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:864:27)[39m
[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)[39m
[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47[39m {
  code: [32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'[39m,
  requireStack: []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro tenta limpar o cache com o comando:

```
npm cache clean -f
npm install npm -g
```

Depois você pode tentar desinstalar novamente com o comando :

```
npm uninstall cordova ionic
```

Caso não consiga fazer a remoção e melhor que remova o node com os comandos:

```
npm uninstall node
apt-get purge npm
```